# List iptables rules as append command

Tags: iptables

A while back I was watching over the shoulder of a Linux guru and he issued a command that listed all the iptables rules in the format of the append commands you would need to issue in order to build them, but despite all my googling and man page searching I can't figure out what he did.

For example if the output from `iptables -nL INPUT` was:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.0.1           tcp dpt:80
```

The output from the command I'm looking for would be something like:

```
1  -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -d 192.168.0.1 -j ACCEPT
```

I seem to remember that it was just another option passed into the standard `iptables -L` command, but I could be wrong.  Does anyone know of a command to accomplish this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's super simple:
`iptables -S`
gives you exactly what you ask for.

Answer (score 4):

You can get similar output by using `iptables-save` command:

```
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [381:53396]
:INPUT ACCEPT [286:22260]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1462:92025]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [1450:91003]
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.123.0/24 ! -d 192.168.123.0/24 -p tcp -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1024-65535 
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.123.0/24 ! -d 192.168.123.0/24 -p udp -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1024-65535
```

There are numbers and some extra info, but you can remove them by writing something like that:

```
iptables-save | grep -v -e "^[*:#]" -e "COMMIT" | cat -n
```

And the output:

```
     1  -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.123.0/24 ! -d 192.168.123.0/24 -p tcp -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1024-65535 
     2  -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.123.0/24 ! -d 192.168.123.0/24 -p udp -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1024-65535
```